# Global Filter as main menu drop down link

Tags: views, routes, taxonomy-terms

I'm looking for right steps to implement [Global Filter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/global_filter) not as a block, but rather as an *main menu* links. The biggest problem is that each user can see only links they have access to (taxonomy access). So it's not possible to make these links static.

I've tried to include a block in the menu link, but that's not what I want.

Has anybody an idea where I could begin?

Comment: I came a little bit forward. I have placed Taxonomy menu exactly how i wanted. But now I only need to replace all automatic generated links taxonomy/term/$id to ?my_filter_field=$id. I can't find where I have to do it. It were very helpfull for me.

Answer (score 1):

To rewrite your taxonomy URLs (you should probably rewrite your question to this end) you can use the following.

```
/*
 * Modify taxonomy uris to point back to facetted search
 */
function my_module_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
  $entity_info['taxonomy_term']['uri callback'] = '_my_module_term_uri';
}

/**
 * Rewrite term URIs to point to our search query.
 */
function _my_module_term_uri($term) {
  $path = null;
  // Do your stuff to get your path correct.

  // Return your path if you've managed to rewrite it.
  if ( $path ) {
    return array(
      'path' => $path,
      'options' => array(), // url style options
    );
  }

  // Otherwise just return the default.
  return taxonomy_term_uri($term);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have found another possibility, but the redirect does not work at all.         function test_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {
      $entity_info['taxonomy_term']['uri callback'] = 'test_taxonomy_term_uri';
    }
     
    function test_taxonomy_term_uri($term) {
      switch ($term->vocabulary_machine_name) {
     
        case 'voc1':
          return array(
            'path' => 'voc1/' . $term->tid,
          );
        break;
   
        default:
          return array(
            'path' => 'no_voc/' . $term->tid,
          );
        break;
      }
    }